# Surrounding Clipboard with quotes in URL

Tags: autohotkey

Warning: I'm very new to this.

I'd like to make Google searches quicker by assigning a hotkey to search a text selection (in web browser) and surrounding that search with quotes (to get exact matches).

I've tried using bits of code I have found, but so far I can only search the selected text on Google, but don't know how to surround the selected text in quotes in the search.

```
^!d:: ;

prevClipboard := ClipboardAll
SendInput, ^c  
ClipWait, 1 
if !(ErrorLevel)  { 
    Clipboard := RegExReplace(RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\r?\n"," "), "(^\s+|\s+$)")
    If SubStr(ClipBoard,1,7)="http://"
Run, % Clipboard
else 
Run, % "https://www.google.com/search?q=" Clipboard
} 
Clipboard := prevClipboard
return
```

This simply opens a google search with the clipboard.
I cannot find out how to make it so "Clipboard" is searched instead of Clipboard.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a **"Phase google search"** from any Selected Text (And From Out Everywhere, on your Computer System.)

Then you can try this AHK Script.

you can [Select any Text] and then you can click the [F1] key from your Keyboard Device.

The Computer Find automatic out where it can do the Query Search (us 100x results) and what Browser it must use.

Example1.ahk

```
;#notrayicon
#SingleInstance force

GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome or Iron
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ; Edge

; here you can change the variable into exact search [
quote1 = "
; here you can change the variable into exact search ]
quote2 = "

; here you can change the variables intitle: - inurl: - inanchor: - allinurl: - allinanchor:
insearch = allintitle:

; + = Shift
; ! = Alt
; ^ = Ctrl
; # = Win (Windows logo key)

esc::exitapp ;You can click the (esc) key to stop the script.

f1::
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
sendinput ^t ;CTRL+t make a new tab + goto address bar - use CTRL+L for the active tab + goto address bar
sleep 150
texta = https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr#q=%insearch%%quote1%
textb = %clipboard%%quote2% ;selected text
textc = &lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=100 ; google parameters

clipboard=%texta%%textb%%textc%
sleep 150
sendinput ^v ; paste the selected text 
sleep 250
send {enter}
clipboard=%textb%
} else {
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
texta = https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr#q=%insearch%%quote1%%quote1%
textb = %clipboard%%quote2%%quote2%%quote2% ;selected text
textc = &lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=100 ; google parameters

clipboard=%texta%%textb%%textc%
run %clipboard%
clipboard=%textb%
}

return
```

Answer (score 1):

Run is a command and [variables in commands](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s61) have to be enclosed in percent signs.

To include an quote, specify two consecutive quotes twice:

```
Run, http://www.google.com/search?q=""%Clipboard%""
```